# Mean Value Theorem for Integrals Problem

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I'm having difficulty getting a proper answer for this problem.  I'm not that good at Mean Value Theorem for Integrals.  Can someone help me find the solution?

> > Find the value(s) of c guaranteed by the Mean Value Theorem for Integrals for the function over the given interval.
> >
> > $f$($x$) = $x^5$,  [0, 5]

Answer (score 1):

The mean value theorem for integrals says that there exists a $c$ for which $f$ agrees with its average; that is,

$$f(c) = \frac1{5 - 0} \int_0^5 f(t) dt$$

So compute the integral

$$\int_0^5 t^5 dt$$ and get a number; you should get $5^6/6$; then solve

$$c^5 = \frac{5^5}{6}$$

Answer (score 0):

[image]
This is the answer I got when I solved it. I hope you understand it.

Comment: You should learn $\LaTeX$-markup, so that you can type your equations!